Azure Managed Instance - Issue with NotifyLogPoolMgr Shrinking Logpool Under Memory Pressure in Database
I'm encountering an issue with our database where the NotifyLogPoolMgr is shrinking the log pool under memory pressure. The specific message in the logs is as follows:
NotifyLogPoolMgr in DB: 5 shrinks logpool under memory pressure for 1 times with decrease percentage: 5.
I'm trying to understand the implications of this message and how to address the underlying issue. Here are some specific questions I have:
What exactly does this message mean?
What are the potential causes for the log pool being shrunk due to memory pressure?
Are there any recommended steps to prevent this from happening in the future?

You'll want to look at the memory consumers and see who spiked/used memory around the time the issue started. LogPool has many uses, CT/CDC/Repl/AG, etc., and you'll need to figure out who is using the memory and why to figure out how to stop it from occurring.

@Lifipe  MemoryManagerInfo SP can help to troubleshoot this issue, shows memory consuption (and by what): https://github.com/aleksey-vitsko/Database-Administrator-Tools/blob/master/Memory%20-%20MemoryManagerInfo.sql

I opened a ticket with MS and they found the issue.
"The reported error messages indicate shrinking of internal pools due to system-level memory pressure. The pressure on the VM level was caused by the infrastructure applications transiently."
